# SharePoint - Document Library - File Size Units?

Tags: 2013, document-library, caml, folder, file

I am fetching file properties from a document library using below query(I am using c#,csom)

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                         <Query>
                               <ViewFields>
                                  <FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' />
                                  <FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Size' />
                              </ViewFields>
                            <Where>
                                <Eq>
                                   <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
                                   <Value Type='int'>0</Value>
                                 </Eq>
                             </Where>
                         </Query>
                       </View>";
```

This works perfectly fine.

The output of file size is :

```
879394
595284
561276
620888
775702
780831
777835
845941
620888
780831
845941
561276
```

I am unable to understand this whether it is in KB or what is the unit and how to interpret this.

Could someone help me here please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`ShowField` in `onet.xml` says `SizeInKB` for this field.

Source: https://books.google.hr/books?id=2r_aYaOx_PAC&pg=PT117&lpg=PT117&dq=File_x0020_Size&source=bl&ots=mDOzdQM77o&sig=rolwgtkG9PtpuIu4z9fYGIoOB9c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu5e_b3sfVAhXE0RQKHRMoDy0Q6AEIVzAJ#v=onepage&q=File_x0020_Size&f=false

Comment: I added SizeInKB to my CAML qry and I got this error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: The results you got are in KB.

Comment: Ok, so I should consider this as KB. Any references in msdn or any such informative links which i can go through? Thank you @Slaven

Comment: For SP 2013 `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\ONET.XML` file contains field definitions. One of these definitions is           `<Field ID="{8fca95c0-9b7d-456f-8dae-b41ee2728b85}" Name="File_x0020_Size" Hidden="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Lookup" DisplayName="$Resources:core,File_Size;" List="Docs" FieldRef="ID" ShowField="SizeInKB" Format="TRUE" JoinColName="DoclibRowId" JoinRowOrdinal="0" JoinType="INNER" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="File_x0020_Size">
          </Field>`